# GZipStream works but extension is lost

Tags: c#, .net, compression, gzipstream

I am using following code to zip a file and it works fine but when I decompress with WinRar I get the original file name without the extension, any clue why if filename is `myReport.xls` when I decompress I get only `myReport` ?

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    byte[] input = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(input, 0, input.Length);
    fs.Close();

    using (var fsOutput = new FileStream(zipName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    using(var zip = new GZipStream(fsOutput, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        zip.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
        zip.Close();
        fsOutput.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK GZip has no idea about files or folders... OTOH ZIP is very different from that since it has all this including file attributes etc. built-in... perhaps you want to use a Zip library ?

Comment: IOW, GZip is a compression format, whereas ZIP is a compressed archive format.  (TAR would be an example of an archive format.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

GZip compresses only one file - without knowing the name. Therefore if you compress the file `myReport.xls` you should name it `myReport.xls.gz`. On decompression the last file extension will be removed so you end up with the original filename.

That its the way how it is used in Unix/Linux for ages...

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue, now solved by simply appending the extension instead of replacing it with .zip.

Answer (score 2):

Very weird indeed.  A brief search came up with the following:

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/discussions/268293

Which says that GZipStream has no way of knowing the name of the stream that is being written, and suggests you set the `FileName` property directly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: no it does not work because the zip object has no Name or FileName property to assign. Tried with .NET 3.5 and .NET 4 but no differences... :(

Comment: @Davide Piras But if you use DotNetZip it has a method `AddFile` - this takes the filename and stores it... GZip is something different from ZIP although the names are rather similar...